# Why am I getting this Error: "Cannot find file './App' in './src'.":?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, create-react-app, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy my react app to aws-amplify but I keep getting this error in the build process in aws.

When I run the app in production, "yarn run build" it runs fine locally, but when I push my changes to aws I get the following error:

```
"Failed to compile.
2020-07-26T15:51:52.356Z [INFO]: ./src/index.js
Cannot find file './App' in './src'.":
```

[more detailed aws error image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot76N.png)

My folder structure is as follows:

```
- public
  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - logo192.png
  - logo512.png
  - manifest.json
  - robots.txt
- src
  - assets
  - components
    - Contact.js
    - Home.js
    - Navigation.js
    - NotFound.js
    - Project.js
    - Projects.js
  - App.css
  - App.js
  - App.test.js
  - contact.css
  - home.css
  - index.css
  - index.js
  - logo.svg
  - projects.css
  - serviceWorker.js
  - setupTest.js
- .gitignore
- package.json
- README.md
- yarn.lock
```

[image: app component]

[screenshot of my index.js and the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ntNE.png)

Comment: try adding `.js` extension and test again.

Comment: I added .js and I received a similar error: "Cannot find file './App.js' in './src'."

Comment: try adding .js extension at the time of importing App component and test again.

Comment: Please share your App component

Comment: I edited the post and added the app component screenshot

Comment: Your App component code is fine. Try with simple test component by replacing your app component and see that it works or not on aws.

Comment: It worked when I created the Test Component, so I changed the name of App Component to Application and it worked! Thank you for leading me to get my application deployed but I am still curious to know why I was receiving the error.

Comment: Can you check if the App.js file is in your remote repository? (e.g. Github or bitbucket)

Comment: Yes it is in my remote repository

Answer (score 2):

You are including file `App.css` but there is only `app.css`. Fix the case of the first letter.

Some operating systems (or better said, some file systems) are case-sensitive. You have to write the name of the file correctly.

If you are using a versioning system (e.g. git), make sure you have renamed the file in the versioning system. On a case-insensitive file system a change in case won't be detected.

Comment: App.css casing is correct in my folder structure, I made a mistake in typing the file structure (I fixed it above), I also included a screenshot of my file structure and the casing is correct there.

Comment: @JessicaDelcy Make sure it's also correct in you versioning system. Clone your repository to a different folder and check the casing.

Comment: @JessicaDelcy - Were you able to get past this? I am facing the same issue with the build (AWS Code Build). I'd really appreciate it if you could post any solution that may have worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

For others that come here:

It's likely you have different casings for your folder or file names in your `master`/`main` and `develop` or other branches.

To make git case sensitive use:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

and then commit again.